# How to add header to a jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to add  header to my autocomplete function.In this autocomplete, I am using a web method to fetch the data from database and i am using `jquery-ui-1.8.16`.
below you can see my autocomplete function

```
$("#sub_Header_PropertyTab1_ucPropertyTabs_AddressTab2_txtPropertyKommunenr").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: './webservices/lookup.asmx/GetKommuneAutocom',
                data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('^')[1] + "-" + item.split('^')[0],

                            val: item.split('^')[2]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            //            alert(i.item.label);
            $("#sub_Header_PropertyTab1_ucPropertyTabs_AddressTab2_txtPropertyKommunenr").val(i.item.val);
            //$("#").val(i.item.val);
            return false;
        },
        focus: function (e, i) {
            $("#sub_Header_PropertyTab1_ucPropertyTabs_AddressTab2_txtPropertyKommunenr").val(i.item.val);
            return false;
        },

        minLength: 1
    });
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please explain what you mean by "add header".

Comment: hi magnus,in autocomplete function if u enter anything in texbox list data will come for that list i need add one header.

Comment: in this link you ill understand better http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/g4stL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the widget autocomplete plugin, and add a custom header to the autocomplete list by overriding the _`renderMenu` function.

Code (with local data):

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];

    $.widget("custom.autocompleteheader", $.ui.autocomplete, {
        _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
            var self = this;
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                self._renderItem(ul, item);
                if (index == 0) ul.prepend('<li class="header-auto"> Header for autocomplete!!</li>');
            });
        }
    });

    $("#tags").autocompleteheader({
        source: availableTags
    });

});
```

Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/rMkER/

Comment: Is this possible to add widget in jquery version jquer-ui-1.8.16

Comment: @user1942546 if solved consider the thick the answer as solved (using the green mark)

Comment: Done:-)..one more question irvin ..in my autocomplete function two values are coming and i am separating values by '-'. Can we separate this data as two columns with two headers.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. I simply added a header item in the list using a prepend in the autocomplete open event.

```
open: function()
  {
    $('ul.ui-autocomplete').prepend('<li><div class="list-header">HEADER</div></li>');
  }
```